# Energy of band of $d$-dimensional semiconductor when voltage $V$ is applied across

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, quantum-transport

Let's say we have a one-dimensional semiconductor and I apply a voltage $V$ across it, I want to calculate the energy of a parabolic band, when a source and drain voltage is applied across it. I expect it to be $U = \Sigma_k \frac{\hbar^2 k^2}{2 m^*}f(k)$ where $f(k)$ is the Fermi function.

When no voltage is applied  $U_0 = \Sigma_k \frac{\hbar^2 k^2}{2 m^*}f_0(k)$

(I am just confused what the Fermi-level should be in the case when voltage is applied and I want to do a full integral including temperature dependence)

My question basically is, what is the expression for $f(k)$ and $f_0(k)$? Would it be different in the ballistic and diffusive regime? And how do I extend this for d-dimensional semiconductors?